# How to hook up discrete ultrasonic sensor pair to Arduino board?

Tags: ultrasound, arduino-uno, flow-sensor

I have a pair of ultrasonic sensors, one of which is a transmitter and the other is a receiver. How do I hook them up to the Arduino board? The board is an Arduino Uno board and the sensors are aluminum encased.

I am using these sensors to build a flowmeter to determine the direction of fluid flow inside a pipe. The theory behind it can be found [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bx2RnrfLkQg).

HC-SR04 sensor modules and stuff don't work as I have a pipe of diameter about one inch and the transmitter needs to be on one side of the pipe and the receiver on the other side of the pipe. That is why I need to use separated sensor modules. They are at an angle and are thus about 12 cm away from each other.

The images of the sensors as well as a diagram of my setup are given below.

[image: Here is the image of the sensors]

[image: Here is the image of the sensors]

[image: Here is the image of the setup]

Thanks!

PS: All images are my own and you have full permission to use them in any way or method you need to.

PPS: I can get common AMP IC's but finding individual resistors and transistors will be difficult, hence please refrain from using these in your answers...

Comment: First of all, you need to provide some more details. What exact sensors and model of Arduino do you have? What have you tried etc.

Comment: The sensors aren't exact per se, they are just a local model... The Arduino is an Uno board... I am confused as to how exactly to hook up the receiver to the board as there are two pins of equal length... The transmitter is somewhat understandable as I need to hook one pin up to the digital pins and one to the ground, but should the receiver be attached to one digital pin and one ground or one digital pin and one 5V?

Comment: Alright, so we are talking about just a discrete piezoelectric transducer and receiver I guess? Then you will have to add some amplification and probably filtering of the output from the receiver. Also regarding the transducer, you should probably add some drive circuitry with higher drive capability than just the Arduino output, in order to get some decent performance. I'd recommend you to use complete, finished modules for this if it's just some hobby project (unless you want to learn everything about building ultrasonic sensors, that is).

Comment: I'm not actually trying to transmit data... just a single pulse every loop which needs to be received by the receiver.

Comment: Plus, I already tried modules but those don't work in my case as the transmitter and receiver need to be far away from each other...

Comment: 1) look on https://www.instructables.com/ if there are projects doing something similar. 2) *the transmitter and receiver need to be far away from each other.* that information should have been in your question and specify what "far away" means so put a number on that 1 m, 10 m, 100 km etc. 3) ultrasonics work in the range of **a few meters** so if your "far away" is more than that, data transfer is not going to work.

Comment: HCSR04 barely works if it's more than 1-1.5 meter. So how much is "far away"?

Comment: about 12 cm through water...

Comment: @AradhyaJain - Hi, You were asked at the start of comments to give details of the *exact* sensors that you have. Until you do that, we have insufficient information to proceed. One answer kindly given so far *might* be inappropriate, as it makes an assumption about the sensors you have, that *could* be invalid. So please, [edit] the question and: (a) add *all* details you have for your current sensors & a photo of them; (b) explain your project e.g. are you detecting water in that pipe?; (c) add a diagram / photo showing relevant distances - why are the sensors 12 cm apart with a 1 inch pipe?

Comment: @SamGibson the issue is that the sensors are a local model which I bought from nearby so I can't provide specifics... Would an image work?

Comment: @AradhyaJain - Hi, I asked for 3 things (a) - (c). So as part of (a) please add whatever details you have about the sensors. If you bought them locally, did they really give you *zero* information about them? If so, then yes, the only thing you can supply for (a) will be a photo or two. (Please still add as much info as you can for points (b) and (c).)  In a comment on an answer, you asked "*Could any of the schematics be simplified by using pre existing amplifier modules*" which is surprising, as some of us guessed you do *not* have pre-made modules. Please add all the info you have.

Comment: I apologize.. I used the wrong term. I meant integrated circuits like the IC 741. @SamGibson

Comment: Consider using the sensor modules but relocating the transmitter with a few inches of wire. (Not the receiver as it probably needs to be located right by a sensitive amplifier).

Comment: @AradhyaJain - Thanks for adding more information. The update didn't answer all of my questions, but it might be enough for someone else to want to write an answer, so I will reopen the question, now that there is significantly more information in the question.

Comment: @SamGibson Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

What you need on the receiver side, is mainly some amplification and demodulation of the signal in order to get something useful to put into an MCU.

Here is one example of circuitry that can be used. This was designed for some ultrasonic obstacle detection using 40kHz transducer/receiver. Depending on your application it might need adjusting.
Vcc is 5V in this circuit.
[image: ultrasonic receiver schematic]
This circuit band-pass filters and amplifies the signal from the receiver and demodulates the 40kHz using a simple envelope detector. The output ("Signal In") can be connected to a digital input of an MCU.

For the driver side, it can be done something like this:
[image: ultrasonic transducer driver schematic]
This is a simple push-pull amplifier which greatly increases the output power of the transducer, compared from just driving it straight from the output of an MCU. There are many ways of designing an amplifier like this, but this one is quite simple.

Comment: @All - *Please be nice* and comply with the site's [Code of Conduct](/help/conduct) (CoC) in everything you write. Nothing snarky / sarcastic / condescending (or worse). Some comments here were deleted after being flagged. [Polite constructive criticism](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756) is allowed in comments - with the emphasis on *polite* & *constructive*. Also please check especially that a comment still complies with the CoC, if it includes the words "you" or "your". Thanks.

Comment: Klas-Kenny - Hi, Are those schematics your own creation? As required by [this site rule](/help/referencing), when you include something in an answer (e.g. photo, image or text) which isn't your own original work, you need to properly reference (cite) it. If those images came from somewhere else, can you please edit your answer and add a link back to the original web page(s) (or add equivalent details if the source was a book e.g. title, author(s), publisher, edition and page number). If you did create the diagrams, please add a small self-citation below them. Thanks.

Comment: @Klas-Kenny Hi, Could any of the schematics be simplified by using pre existing amplifier modules or something?